# Emulating a linux/bash shell in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, terminal

So I am basically looking for the easiest approach here, what I want as a result is an in-game-linux-shell (will be rendered using opengl and sfml), that will emulate/simulate a linux box.
It doesn't need to be all that fancy, what I prioritize is the basics (ls, grep, cat, echo..), some kind of editor (vim/nano-like), and that the game logic can interact with /dev, /etc etc.

I've thought about chrooting an environment, but I see more issues than solutions doing so. Also thought about if there is some kind of popular linux emulator written in C++ which can be  tightly integrated with the hostcode, this is a longshot and I haven't found anything yet.

Any help in getting me on the right path is hugely appreciated!

PS. The end-product will be cross-plattform (at least for win / linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) which is a small and freely available implementation of many features of a Linux command line.  You should be able to embed it in your game without too much trouble.  You'll also have to model separately the filesystem and the tty interface, of course.

Comment: Havent even thought about busybox! Perhaps I could use its sourcecode to build my own "integrated ingame OS" and maintain that code crossplatform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

I would implement the directory structure as a tree of nodes (kind of like a linked list, however, each parent could have any number of children). Then if you wanted to run the following commands (I know, these are not all the commands in Linux, but this should still give you a good idea of what I am saying) they should behave as such:

- `ls` - Simple look at the current node and list all children
- `ls -R` - Look at the current node and list all children recursively (see [wikipedia's tree traversal page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal))
- `cd /some/path` - Split `/some/path` based on the `/`s and then try to change the present working directory (this should probably be implemented as a pointer to a node) to the path that user specified. If the path is absolute (i.e. beginning with `/` its membership in the directory structure should be easily verifiable simply by trying to locate it from the root node.

This brings me to another point. Since your structure is a tree of nodes, you *should* have two types of nodes: nodes representing files, and those representing directories. Directories may have children, files may not. Also, file nodes may have an associated set of data (probably a string) that could be the file's contents (since you are wanting to be able to edit files).

- `rm somefile` - Simply nullifies a child node if it exists in the present working directory.
- `mkdir somedir` - Attaches a new directory node to the present working, iff `somedir` doesn't already exist.
- `rmdir somedir` - Removes a directory node named `somedir` from the present working directory if it has no children.

Now the above only really talks about the directory structure, and I could keep listing commands and how they would be implemented but I think you get the point so far. So, I'll talk about the other commands you listed (`grep`, `cat`, `echo`, `vim/nano`).

- As far as implementing grep goes, with my above structure, making a very primitive implementation would be fairly easy. You would simply have to loop through each line of the file (in this case this would be the data associated with a file node) and do a string compare on each line, print the matches. If you are permitting regexs then I cannot help you, and I would suggest looking at the [c++ regular expressions library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/). However, **there is an alternative.** `grep` is open source, and therefore you can use its source OR simply read it and understand how it's implemented. [Grep's source code](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/).
- "Catting" a file or many would be simple with the above tree structure. You would just `cout` all the data associated with the files' node(s) sequentially. But also, like `grep` cat is OSS (open source software).
- `echo` should be quite trivial to implement. Simply print back its argument. At least a remedial form of echo (although I'm not really sure echo gets more complicated than this.
- As for implementing vim/nano or something like it. I can't really help you. Again I am inclined to direct you towards their source code ([vim](http://www.vim.org/sources.php), [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php)). However, I realize that this may not be extremely helpful because both are large projects.

Comment: PS, I know I have a lot of just use/read the source type comments above. I believe (as do others) that reading the source of well coded projects (and poorly coded projects for that matter) is one of the best ways to learn and advance as a programmer.

Comment: I have thought about this, but it would require a tremendous ammount of work. I agree in that the best way to advance as a programmer is to  study other peoples work, but this is too much studying/work; This part of the game is not a big enough asset in it for me to spend that much time working on it. Also my goal is to create a realistic feeling of the bash shell and a linux system, to let the user win the game based off his true knowledge about bash/linux, as well as his preference on HOW he uses certain commands (think really complicated grep-arguments for example).

Comment: That is very understandable. Happy coding, friend.

Comment: You could run some cheap VM, e.g. Qemu, with a mini Linux.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That was a though I just had! Sure, you could use a DSL linux installation on a VM and then run it with VBox or something.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The thing is I'd have to interact with the system very closely. The user should be able to do "echo 0 > /dev/camera3", and the gamelogic should be able to recognize this and act upon it in close to realtime.